# Making sure that SSH key is NOT used anywhere but specific hosts

Tags: ssh, configuration

I have an SSH key for work that I do NOT want to be offered by the forwarding agent anywhere but the work hosts.

So I thought following `~/.ssh/config` could do the trick:

```
Host *
    ForwardAgent yes
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host workhost.example.com
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/work_key
```

Does it do what I intend? If not, obviously please answer how to achieve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this configuration uses `~/.ssh/work_key` for `workhost.example.com` only.

From [ssh_config(5)](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config):

> **IdentitiesOnly**
> Specifies that ssh(1) should only use the authentication identity files configured in the ssh_config files, even if ssh-agent(1) offers more identities. The argument to this keyword must be ''yes'' or ''no''. This option is intended for situations where ssh-agent offers many different identities. The default is ''no''.
>
> **IdentityFile**
> Specifies a file from which the user's RSA or DSA authentication identity is read. The default is `~/.ssh/identity` for protocol version 1, and `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and `~/.ssh/id_dsa` for protocol version 2. Additionally, any identities represented by the authentication agent will be used for authentication.

On the other hand, you might want to reverse the order, because:

> Since the first obtained value for each parameter is used, more host-specific declarations should be given near the beginning of the file, and general defaults at the end.

It is also good to understand that ***offering* the key does not compromise it**, because only the hash of the key is sent to the server to be compared with the public keys in the `authorized_keys` file. The process is explained in detail in, e.g., Justin Ellingwood's tutorial on [Understanding the SSH Encryption and Connection Process](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-the-ssh-encryption-and-connection-process#authenticating-the-user-s-access-to-the-server):

> Authentication using SSH key pairs begins after the symmetric
> encryption has been established as described in the previous section.
> The procedure happens as follows:
>
> - The client begins by sending an ID for the key pair it would like to authenticate with to the server.
> - The server checks the `authorized_keys` file of the account that the client is attempting to log into for the key ID.
> - If a public key with a matching ID is found in the file, the server generates a random number and uses the public key to encrypt the
>   number.
> - The server sends the client this encrypted message.
> - If the client actually has the associated private key, it will be able to decrypt the message using that key, revealing the original
>   number.
> - The client combines the decrypted number with the shared session key that is being used to encrypt the communication, and calculates the
>   *MD5 hash* of this value. MD5 is a message-digest algorithm that uses
>   the hash function to generate a 128-bit hash value.
> - The client then sends this MD5 hash back to the server as an answer to the encrypted number message.
> - The server uses the same shared session key and the original number that it sent to the client to calculate the MD5 value on its own. It
>   compares its own calculation to the one that the client sent back. If
>   these two values match, it proves that the client was in possession of
>   the private key and the client is authenticated.

Comment: That page's description of pubkey userauth is partly wrong -- including the point you extract -- for SSH1, and entirely obsolete for over a decade. The full publickey _is_ sent to the server in SSH2, and effectively the full key was even in SSH1, but that doesn't weaken security because the whole point of public-key cryptography is that the public key(s) can be public. However, there is still often a reason not to send the wrong publickey(s) to an OpenSSH server -- if you send too many wrong keys (before the correct one) it may treat you as an attacker and block you.

Comment: Could you point me to a better source that has these details right?

Comment: rfc 4252 plus section 6.6 of 4253, updated by 5656 8332 8709 . Or an open-source implementation such as OpenSSH libssh PuTTY (and its forks) Jsch (preferably the mwiede fork) sshj paramiko.